# Call function IF boolean variable value is FALSE

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

I am having query to **improve way of writing code** in ES6.

I am calling a function when my variable sets to `FALSE`

Initially `this.myVariable` sets to `true` but under some logic it becomes `false` and I call a function when my boolean is `false`

```
if(!this.myVariable) {
     this.onClearSearch();
}
```

I am new to ES6 So i want to know is there any way to write this in some better way or one liner. This could be a very small logic but still it might give me better understanding to improve my code and logic.

**Note : My Solution is also working.**

Comment: There is nothing specific to ECMAScript 2016 here also ECMAScript is a Javascript standard, not typescript

Answer (score 4):

There are no magic syntax in es6/7/8 that will improve the piece of code you showed to us.

Thought there are some alternative syntaxes you probably already know of.

I would personnaly recommand to you the styles A or B, because they are easy to understand and quick to write.

```js
function onClearSearch() {
  console.log('call');
}

const myVariable = false;

// Writting style A
if (!myVariable) {
  onClearSearch();
}

// Writting style B
if (myVariable == false) {
  onClearSearch();
}

// Writting style C
if (myVariable == false) onClearSearch();

// Writting style D
myVariable || onClearSearch();

// Writting style E
myVariable ? void 0 : onClearSearch();

// Writting style F
myVariable ? _ : onClearSearch();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following idiom is quite common in React code for conditional rendering:

```
!this.myVariable && this.onClearSearch()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check exactly for the value `false`, you can do it like this:

```
if (this.myVariable === false) {
  this.onClearSearch();
}
```

Note that I used the triple equal comparator (`===`) to check for value and also type.

You can also of course do it the same you did it with `!this.myVariable` but that would also be true for "falsy" values like `0` or `''` (the empty string).

If that's what you meant, I recommend you to check the concepts of [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JavaScript.